# Why does my killer fish only have 1hp?

Tags: tales-of-symphonia-hd

In Tales of Symphonia: New Dawn, when Lailah resurrects my Killer Fish in battle, I notice he always seems to have 1hp immediately after. Once or twice I've seen the res go off for 700+ hp, but the fish only gains 1 from that. Is there some reason this is happening so I can prevent it? It sucks having him at 1hp for most of the battle.